# Change background of linearlayout on focus in Android?

Tags: android, focus, android-linearlayout

I have the linearlayout which has the background set as rect.xml as mentioned below. The orientation of this layout is vertical.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle"> 
<solid android:color="#ffffff"/>    

<stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#bbbbbb"/>

<corners android:radius="10px"/> 
</shape>
```

There are two other linearlayouts as child of the above linearlayout. What I want is that the child linearlyouts focus should be changed on focus and when pressed. I have created one item selector file and added that as the background of the child linearlayouts but that makes the border of the rectangle hidden.

Can anyone let me know how to do this?

Comment: you need to change button effect?like onlick it change background or some highlighted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use state list drawable and provide different background.xml

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: I have tried using the state list drawable but that gives the focus as rectangle with pointed corners but the layout that is generated with above rect.xml is rounded corners. So, for the first and last element the focus should be rounded corners.